# Don't understand why this variable cannot be resovled to a type? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I'm trying to make a game for an assignment called `PegSwap`. They dynamics of the game aren't important, but the "board" is a board with 7 spaces. 3 red pegs, 3 blue pegs, at random positions, with a blank spot in the middle. All I'm trying to do is randomly generate the initial positions of each peg. Here is my code:

```
package game;

import java.util.List;

public class PegGame implements GameState {

//numbers corresponding to beg color to be used in list
private final int BLANK = 3;
private final int BLUE = 1;
private final int RED = 2;

//list that maintains peg at position i
private int[] pegs = new int[7];

//generates a randomized start state for the board
public int[] startState(){

    int blues = 0;// how many blues have been added so far?
    int reds = 0; //how many reds have been added so far?
    pegs[3] = 3; //puts blank spot in the center

    for(int i = 1; i<6; i++){

        if(i == 3) break;

        else if(blues < 3 && reds < 3) pegs[i] = (int) (Math.random()*2);
        else{
            if(blues == 3) pegs[i] = 2;
            if(reds == 3)pegs[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    return pegs;
}
```

The problem is, where I refer to the integer list `pegs` in the 'startState' method, (the line that says `pegs[3] = 3`) Eclipse is giving me an error, saying `pegs` is an unresolved type. Why is it unresolved if I declare it to be an integer array right above the method? I don't get the error on any other references to `pegs`. I thought maybe it was because `pegs` has to be passed into `startState`, but this just gives me more errors saying that `pegs` must be static. Can anyone help?

Edit:
Could it really be because it's private? Doesn't that just mean it can't be accessed in other classes? I also had to write a winState method, and the references to `pegs` rose no errors at all, it is just that one refernce.

```
public int[] winState(){
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        if(pegs[i] == 3) pegs[i] = 3;
        if(pegs[i] == 2) pegs[i] = 1;
        if(pegs[i] == 1) pegs[i] = 2;
    }
    return pegs;
}
```

Comment: @user1354678 WHAT? You mean that class methods can not access their own class fields?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project? those two lines are syntactically valid (the declaration and the access)

Comment: could it be that your startState() method is in fact a static method ?

Comment: Other than the missing closing brace on your class, there's nothing wrong with your code. There's something you're not showing us. Also, why declare constants for your values if you don't use them? (eg `pegs[3] = 3` instead of `pegs[3] = BLANK`)

Comment: Do a clean and build

Comment: BTW, `startState` is a method NOT a class

Comment: I'm not sure, wouldn't it have to be set to static right there in the method declaration?

Comment: oh oops, typo, yes startState is a method

Comment: @user2407420, not necessarily, you can access static and non-static members inside of a non-static method regardless their access modifier (in the same class). Inside of a static method you can only access static members unless you have a reference to an instance (not your case btw)

Comment: set to static right there in method declaration? Bro static members are not declared in method. They are class level.

Comment: I fixed it. I literally just deleted the line and retyped it. Must have been an Eclipse bug. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is problem in your code.
This should work. Try cleaning and rebuilding.

If doesn't work.
Please provide what exactly problem given at your console.

Comment: I fixed it. I literally just deleted the line and retyped it. Must have been an Eclipse bug. Thanks everyone